Switching order of limits for linear operators
Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $(x_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}x_m=x$. Let $(T_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of linear compact operators from $X$ to $Y$ and $T$ be a linear continuous operator from $X$ to $Y$ such that for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} T_n(x_m)=T(x_m)$ in $Y$. In this case, can we change order of limits, namely,
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}T_n(x_m) = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_n(x_m)$ ?
I guess that we can, however, I cannot see how to show this fact. Or should we put extra conditions on the sequence $(T_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ ?

Yes. Quite silly of me.

In general, no. Consider $X=Y=H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space with ONB $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.  Let $$x_m=\sum_{n=1}^m 2^{-n}e_n$$ and define $$T_nx=4^n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.$$ Let $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}e_n$ and let $T$ be the zero operator on $H$. Then for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $T_n(x_m)=0=T(x_m)$ for all $n>m$. But $T_nx=4^n e_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So $$\lim_m \lim_n T_n(x_m) = \lim_m 0=0$$ but $$\lim_n \lim_m \|T_n(x_m)\|=\lim_n \|T_n x\|=\infty.$$
The result holds if we add the requirement that $\sup_n \|T_n\|<\infty$. This is a consequence of what's sometimes called the partial converse to the principle of uniform boundedness. If $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $S$ are continuous linear operators from the Banach space $E$ into the Banach space $F$, and if $\sup_n \|S_n\|<\infty$, then $$G:=\{e\in E:\lim_n S_ne=Se\}$$ is a closed subspace of $E$. It's quite clearly a subspace, so only closedness needs to be shown. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and  $e\in \overline{G}$. Let $s=1+\max\{\|S\|, \sup_n \|S_n\|\}$.  Fix $e_0\in G$ such that $\|e-e_0\|<\frac{\epsilon}{3s}$ and note that there exist $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_0$, $\|Se_0-S_ne_0\|<\epsilon/3$.  Then for all $n\geqslant n_0$, \begin{align*} \|Se-S_ne\| & \leqslant \|Se-Se_0\|+\|Se_0-S_ne_0\|+\|S_ne_0-S_ne\| \\ & \leqslant \|S\|\|e-e_0\|+\|S_n\|\|e-e_0\|+\|Se_0-S_ne_0\|<\epsilon.\end{align*}

Can we modify your result if we assume that $T\neq 0$ (and $T_n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ )?

Do you mean rule out counterexamples of the type I provided? That doesn't help, because if we take my counterexamples $(T_n){n=1}^\infty$ and $T$, then for any compact $S$, $(S+T_n){n=1}^\infty$ and $S+T$ also serve as a counterexample. So you could translate to make them all non-zero and still get the counterexample.

Ok, now I see the point, it doesn't matter to start with a non-zero $T$, as your counterexample could be modified easily to the non-zero case, as you explained.

To get the result that you want, we don't actually need $(T_n){n=1}^\infty$ to be uniformly bounded on the whole domain. Only on the span of the $(x_m){m=1}^\infty$.

If $M$ is the subspace generated by $(x_m){m=1}^\infty$, do you mean we only need $\displaystyle\sup{n\in\mathbb{N}}||T_n|M||<\infty$ instead of $\displaystyle\sup{n\in\mathbb{N}}||T_n||<\infty$ ?

That's correct. It's sufficient to check on the (unclosed) span of the $(x_m){m=1}^\infty$, since Lipschitz continuity on a set implies Lipschitz continuity on the closure (with the same constant). Moreover, by PUB, it's automatically true that for each $m$, $$d_m:= \sup_n |T_n|{\text{span}{x_1,\ldots, x_m}}|<\infty.$$  If $\sup_m d_m<\infty$, we're good.

Given $m\in\mathbb{N}$, to use PUB (in order to have $d_m<\infty$), I think you use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_jT(x_j)$ for each $\displaystyle x=\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_jx_j\in span{x_1,...,x_m}$, am I right?

Yes, that's exactly right.
